# why assigning a value to an variable doesn't work here?

Tags: python, variables, output, comparison

I did a programming challenge in codewars, I got stuck, and I have no clue why I this code deosn't give me the results I desire.
here is my code:

```
     def magic_plant(p_field,split,n):
       b=n
       while(n>0):
          p_field=p_field[:-2]
          if(p_field=="o"):
              break
          n=n-1
       z=p_field*(split^b)
       return(z) 
    print(magic_plant("o\n|\n|",3,3))
```

here is the challenge, it explains it way clear than I would:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/6339de328a3b8f0016cc5b8d
my intention from this code is to provide to the variable z the variables with the given values:

```
b = n = 3
split = 3 
p_field = "o"
```

and as a result, idealy print `z` and thus get the output:

```
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

(27 o's, as per the calculation)
instead my output is nothing:
 
I tried to see what is the root of the problem, and eventually came to realize that the bug lies at line 2 (`b=n`).
if I neglect that line, then I get `o` as an output.
what is going on here? why do I get such results in the first place-  for `b=n`, and `o` for not writing `b=n`?

Comment: What do you mean by the expression: `split^b`? Did you mean: `split**b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split^b` should be `split**b`. ^ is the XOR operator in python, not the exponent operator.